# Sitecore8 multisite sitedefinition not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I have the below `sitedefintion.config` in my sitecore instance. I can't figure out what is wrong with this one. When I view the `holding.somedomain.com` and `somedomain-miles.somedomain.com` it gives me "The requested document was not found" error.

I already verified that the site has a layout. I think the sitedefinition is not working.

What I did so far:

- Configure IIS (Created three separate websites).
- Modify host file.

See my site definition:

```xml
  <site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="rootPath">/sitecore/content/somedomain</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="hostName">somedomain.com</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="startItem">/home</patch>     
  </site>

  <site name="somedomainholdings" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        virtualFolder="/"
        hostName="holdings.somedomain.com"
        physicalFolder="/"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/somedomainholdings"
        startItem="/home"
        database="web"
        domain="extranet"
        allowDebug="true"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="50MB"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableWebEdit="true"
        enableDebugger="true"
        disableClientData="false"/>

    <site name="somedomainmiles" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        virtualFolder="/"
        hostName="somedomain-miles.somedomain.com"
        physicalFolder="/"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/somedomainmiles"
        startItem="/home"
        database="web"
        domain="extranet"
        allowDebug="true"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="50MB"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableWebEdit="true"
        enableDebugger="true"
        disableClientData="false"/>
```

Comment: Can you check `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx" what is the generated `<sites>` section? Can you login to Sitecore Desktop, switch to `web` database and check whether all the items are there and whether they have layouts configured?

Comment: Only the first one (website) is modified in the web.config. The other two is not added. Any ideas why?

Comment: Verified that layouts are configured both in web and master.

Comment: You patch file looks ok. Can you try to reorder the file so you have: `<site name="somedomainholdings"`, then `<site name="somedomainmiles"`, and then `<site name="website">     <patch:attribute...`?

Comment: It doesn't work. But when I put it directly in the web.config it works.

Comment: I don't know why this patch is not applied. I've never experienced such an issue before. Anyway, I'm glad you have a workaround :) . If you want to investigate it further - are all those patch values inside one file? When you look at showconfig.aspx, do you see `patch:source` attribute inside your `<site name='website'` tag and does it point to this file?

Comment: Finally got it worked! The issue is the closing </patch> at the end of <site name='website'>. It should be </patch:attribute>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it worked! The issue is the closing `</patch>` at the end of `<site name='website'>`. It should be `</patch:attribute>`.

Marek Musielak, pointed me out on the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your site definitions file should look something like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="mysite" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content"
            startItem="/home"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="10MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"/>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Also, your IIS configuration should be a single site (probably). Each IIS site counts as a Sitecore instance (and thus counts against your instance number as part of your Sitecore license).

Comment: Yes, my site definition is like that. I run into problem copy and paste it here so i just copy the <site> element.

Comment: be carefull, when you forget the "/" at the end of the xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig" its not working!

Answer (score 1):

You should configure IIS to have only one site for Sitecore with all the bindings for all the different sites in your site definitions added to it. Sitecore is designed to run once on a server and there are many caches that are shared between sites. Also, you should try changing the `Database` setting to `master` to rule out a publishing issue.

You should also check that the app pool is running clr version 4 and that you have the .net framework installed correctly